# Quickly template for PyQt?

Tags: python, application-development, qt, quickly, pyqt

Because I like Qt and Python, is there a Quickly template for PyQt similar to the PyGTK one?

Comment: Want to make one? I've been looking for something to scratch my itch with.

Answer (score 6):

There are some ongoing attempts to create a Quickly template. You might have a look at the following if you'd like to contribute or try them out:

- [Qt and QtQuick Quickly templates](https://launchpad.net/quickly-community-templates)
- [How to create a Quickly template](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136850/how-to-create-a-new-quickly-application-template)

Answer (score 4):

There is not a Qt template yet, no.  As a maintainer of Quickly, we'd love to add one, but we've just been busy with other things.  I'd be happy to mentor someone willing to develop one.