# How do I use a quickly community template (e.g. ubuntu-application-qt)?

Tags: python, quickly

I would like to look at the Qt and QtQuick templates for quickly. The documentation for them seems to be non-existent. But I found a previously answered question (http://askubuntu.com/questions/25671/quickly-template-for-pyqt?lq=1) with an answer that links to the Launchpad project with community templates. After clicking around for a while, I stumbled on a PPA that I could follow directions to add in the development team on Launchpad. After I added the PPA, I could successfully install the package with `sudo aptitude install quickly-community-templates-common`. However, it seems that I still only have the three default templates available from quickly:

```
$ quickly create ubuntu-application-qt myproject
ERROR: No template specified for command create.
Usage: quickly create <template> <project-name>
Candidate templates are: ubuntu-application, ubuntu-cli, ubuntu-flash-game
```

I went to Launchpad and put this up as a bug. But they have a bug from 16/6 that still isn't answered, so it doesn't seem to be much activity there. And I'm not sure if this is a bug or if it's just a result of me not understanding anything about how to use this since there is no documentation. So I'm asking the question here instead: how do I use these templates for quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer through e-mail from David Planella on my bug submission;

```
For now, you will need to manually install the quickly-ubuntu-
application-qt-template package to be able to use the Qt templates.

In the near future, we'll look into having a metapackage that installs
all templates at once.
```

So installing the metapackage like I did currently does nothing, apparently. Instead, one have to know to install the individual packages for each template. But I tried it and it does indeed work.

However, these templates are not for PyQt4! They are for PySide. So I have to do some serious editing, but at least this links "quickly design" to Qt Designer. One step forward at least.

Answer (score 0):

Templates which are prepackaged with quickly  ubuntu-application, ubuntu-cli and ubuntu-flash-game only ,you can install quickly-unity-lens-template from software center ,other templates still under development ,

**How do I use a quickly template?**

```
      quickly create template_name name_of_the_app
```

Eg,`quickly create ubuntu-application jotty`

Comment: My question is about the community templates, I will clarify the headline to reflect this, even though it should be obvious from the text.