# How to create an Ubuntu app using python and Qt4 designer

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, glade, pyqt

I recently started developing Ubuntu desktop apps using Quickly. But then I tried out the Qt4 designer and I feel more comfortable with it than Glade designer that Quickly uses. I liked developing with Quickly except for the part where Glade comes in. So my question is, is there a possibly way of using Qt4 designer to set up my GUI and use python to do the coding? Also how do I do the packaging after writing the code since in Quickly everything gets done in a single command 'quickly package' and you get a .deb package file. I have done a lot of searching around but haven't found a good tutorial.

Comment: I don't have much experience with Qt, but the two main Python bindings for it are pyside and pyqt. I believe the former does not yet have support for Python 3, but is more high-level and is licensed under the LGPL, and the latter has support for Python 3 and with better documentation, but is also licensed under the GPL and also more low-level. PyQt is also the most used.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Quickly template for PyQt?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25671/quickly-template-for-pyqt)

Comment: This is probably too broad to answer in this site. Here is a quick tutorial (http://wiki.python.org/moin/JonathanGardnerPyQtTutorial)